# Django custom admin dashboard error

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I tried to use django-grappelli dashboard, and the admin interface is giving error.

```
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named dashboard

In template /.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/dashboard/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 32
31  {% block content %}
32  {% grp_render_dashboard %}
33  {% endblock %}
```

I could able to use the grappelli admin interface prior to the change.
Steps taken were according to the [manual](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html).
I added these to my settings.py

```
    GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'myproj.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'
    ...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'grappelli.dashboard',
        'grappelli',
        'django.contrib.admin',
         ...
```

dashboard.py is in the root directory (myproj). and it had a class in it.

```
 class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):

myproj
├── admin
│   ├── css
:
├── dashboard.py
├── grappelli
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── backgrounds
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, it got working. dashboard.py needed to move to myproj/myproj

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem! Thank you for your answer, but it seems that your answer is so simplified that I initially could not understand it. Allow me to elaborate so that others may be able to resolve similar issues.

Suppose you have a directory structure like this:

```
 myproj
    ├── myproj

    ├── settings.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── grappelli
    │   ├── ...
    ├── myapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
```

After you execute the following:

```
    python manage.py customdashboard
```

The `dashboard.py` is generated in the `myproj` (the first one) directory, the directory structure will look something like this:

```
myproj
├── myproj
├── dashboard.py
├── settings.py
├── manage.py
├── urls.py
├── grappelli
│   ├── ...
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
```

You should put the `dashboard.py` file in the `myproj/myproj` directory. Then you login to the adminsite and you will find it works. This is not clearly described in the [Dashboard Setup](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html)